Time Complexity of my Subset Sum Problem's Solution
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> subsetsRec(int i,vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<vector<int>> ans;
        if(i==0){
            vector<int> curr1;
            vector<int> curr2;
            ans.push_back(curr2);
            curr1.push_back(nums[i]);
            ans.push_back(curr1);
            return ans;
        }

        vector<vector<int>> restAns=subsetsRec(i-1,nums);

        for (int k = 0; k < restAns.size(); k++)
        {
            ans.push_back(restAns[k]);
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < restAns.size(); k++)
        {   
            restAns[k].push_back(nums[i]);
            ans.push_back(restAns[k]);
        }
        return ans;
    }
    vector<vector<int>> subsets(vector<int>& nums) {
        return subsetsRec(nums.size()-1,nums);
    }
};


What will be the time complexity of this code
T(n)=T(n-1)+2^n
According to this relation
It is coming out as 2^n , but everywhere it says that time complexity is n*2^n

Please read tag descriptions. This is not dsa.
